# How to associate universal time to CLLocation objects?

Tags: ios, timestamp, core-location, cllocationmanager, utc

I need my iOS 7+ app to get a certain number of locations to send them to a server when possible, even if the app is running in background. As far as I know, the timestamp of `CLLocation` is not the GPS time, but the device's time. Since this time can be set by the user, and she can change it whenever she wants, and that I need to listen for locations even if there is no network reachability (so I can't depend on a time server, at least in such scenario), I don't know how could I associate a reliable timestamp to locations... I'd appreciate some help with this, since I need to prevent users from "cheating" the time they reach certain places.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that this is really possible without network communication. You could show a pop up for user that Internet connection is required and check time from the server. Otherwise user can cheat